# Hibernate NamedQuery UPDATE statement throws QuerySyntaxException

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin, jpa

I encountered a very interesting issue. I want to create an `UPDATE` statement `NamedQuery` for my class (I know this is a bit hacky).

The weird thing is if I use positioned parameters in the query like `?1, ?2` etc. it works perfectly. However, if I want to use named parameters like `:id`, it fails with the following error:

`failed because of: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting EOF, found 'consumingTxId' near line 1`.

I'm using Kotlin btw.

My entity:

```
class StateDetailEntity(
        @Id
        @Column(name = "issue_tx_id")
        val issueTxId: String,

        @Column(name = "consuming_tx_id")
        val consumingTxId: String?
)
```

My named query:

```
NamedQuery(
                name = "StateDetailEntity.consume",
                query = "UPDATE StateDetailEntity SET " +
                        "consumingTxId = :consumingTxId " +
                        "WHERE issueTxId = :issueTxId " +
                        "AND consumingTxId IS NULL"
)
```

If I add an alias to the table and re-write the name query to like `UPDATE StateDetailEntity s SET...` I get the following error:

`org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting EOF, found 's'`.

The funny thing is if I change the query like this:

```
NamedQuery(
                name = "StateDetailEntity.consume",
                query = "UPDATE StateDetailEntity SET " +
                        "consumingTxId = ?1 " +
                        "WHERE issueTxId = ?2 " +
                        "AND consumingTxId IS NULL"
)
```

There are no issues at all. Any ideas? Using Hibernate `5.4.32.Final`.

Comment: `"WHERE issueTxId = :issueTxId" + "AND consumingTxId IS NULL"`  no space between `:issueTxId` and next lines `AND`

Comment: Sorry that was just a copy-paste failure, but the spaces are there in the code. Modified my original post.

Comment: In that case, you need to transition to `NamedNativeQuery`, as you are implementing a native query instead of one using JPQL. [howtodoinjava guide](https://howtodoinjava.com/jpa/jpa-native-update-sql-query-example/) on how to implement `NamedNativeQuery` for updates